# cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems, bcrypt

I have added authentication in my rails app using devise, everything worked fine, but when i was trying to signup i got this error:

```
LoadError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext
```

I looked into my gemfile and found that the bcrypt gem is missing so i installed it but this doesn't solved my problem

While searching i read somewhere that i have to restart the server after installing the bcrypt gem i tried that and now when i try to start the server i get this error:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require': cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext (LoadError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
    from C:/Sites/pro/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

**my gemfile**

```
    source 'http://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Rails Server & Database Gems
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.2'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

# Twitter Bootstrap
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.7'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'

# Authentication
gem 'devise'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.11'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'yebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: This solved it for me: https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/142

Comment: Try without bcrypt gem

Answer (score 0):

try gem 'devise', github: 'plataformatec/devise'

bundle update
bundle install